# Convert java.time.LocalDate to java.util.Date

Tags: java, simpledateformat, java.util.date

I have java.time.LocalDate Object in yyyy-MM-dd format.
I would like to know how to convert this to java.util.Date with MM-dd-yyyy format. getStartDate() method should be able to return Date type object with the format MM-dd-yyyy.

**DateParser class**

```
package com.accenture.javadojo.orgchart;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeParseException;
import java.util.Locale;


    public class DateParser {

        public static LocalDate parseDate(String strDate){

            try{
                if((strDate != null) && !("").equals(strDate)){

                    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/yyyy").withLocale(Locale.US);
                    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(strDate, formatter);
                    return date;
                }
            } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

    }
```

---

```
public Date getStartDate() {

    String fmd = format.format(startDate); 

    LocalDate localDate = DateParser.parseDate(fmd);

    return startDate;
}
```

Comment: A `Date` doesn't have a format.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I didn't get you. Can you explain little more please.

Comment: You say _return Date type object with the format MM-dd-yyyy_. A `Date` object is just a timestamp. It doesn't have a format. If you want a format, use a `SimpleDateFormat` and `format` the `Date`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis If you check the getStartDate() method below, you will see i have LocalDate object. But method is returning Date type object. So what i want to do is, convert localDate object to util Date object.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a `LocalDate` which you want to convert to a `Date`, use

> ```
> LocalDate localDate = ...;
> Instant instant = localDate.atStartOfDay().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant();
> Date res = Date.from(instant);
> ```
>
> source: http://blog.progs.be/542/date-to-java-time

You can then use a `SimpleDateFormat` to format the `Date` to whatever format you like.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SimpleDateFormat to switch between LocalDate and Date objects.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public Date getStartDate() {

        String fmd = format.format(startDate); 

        LocalDate localDate = DateParser.parseDate(fmd);

        SimpleDateFormat actual = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        SimpleDateFormat wanted = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");

        String reformatted = wanted.format(actual.parse(localDate.toString()));
        Date date = wanted.parse(reformatted);
        return date;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for response. But it didnt work. I printed localDate and it was: 1907-01-01. Then I printed "date" and it was like this: 
Tue Jan 01 00:00:00 EST 1907

Comment: Reason for downvote? Date is an object as mentioned by @SotiriosDelimanolis response in comment above! If you need to display it as formatted string with MM-dd-yyy format then at the place where you make a call to getStartDate() method use something like  `SimpleDateFormat wanted = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy"); wanted.format(date.toString());`