# How to Use Formatted Text Fields with LocalDate type?

Tags: java, swing, date, eclipselink, localdate

I'm using swing and trying to convert one date from  database, I used the master detail to generate my form!
When I am using it with Date type, it's works  fine, but when I try to use with LocalDate it I get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.jdesktop.beansbinding.PropertyResolutionException: Exception invoking method public void javax.swing.JFormattedTextField.setValue(java.lang.Object) on javax.swing.JFormattedTextField[,71,210,541x28,layout=javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTextUI$UpdateHandler,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthBorder@64d52f45,flags=288,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,caretColor=,disabledTextColor=DerivedColor(color=142,143,145 parent=nimbusDisabledText offsets=0.0,0.0,0.0,0 pColor=142,143,145,editable=true,margin=javax.swing.plaf.InsetsUIResource[top=0,left=0,bottom=0,right=0],selectedTextColor=DerivedColor(color=255,255,255 parent=nimbusSelectedText offsets=0.0,0.0,0.0,0 pColor=255,255,255,selectionColor=DerivedColor(color=57,105,138 parent=nimbusSelectionBackground offsets=0.0,0.0,0.0,0 pColor=57,105,138,columns=0,columnWidth=0,command=,horizontalAlignment=LEADING]
```

This is my form:

package br.com.imprimindo.conteudo.itext;

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.beans.Beans;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.RollbackException;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Form extends JPanel {

    public Form() {
        initComponents();
        if (!Beans.isDesignTime()) {
            entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {
        bindingGroup = new org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BindingGroup();

        entityManager = java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime() ? null : javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("APPPU").createEntityManager();
        query = java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime() ? null : entityManager.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Produto p");
        list = java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime() ? java.util.Collections.emptyList() : org.jdesktop.observablecollections.ObservableCollections.observableList(query.getResultList());
        masterScrollPane = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        masterTable = new javax.swing.JTable();
        idLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        codigoLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        ddvLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        descricaoLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        estoqueLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        valorLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        idField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        codigoField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        descricaoField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        estoqueField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        valorField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        saveButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        refreshButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        newButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        deleteButton = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jFormattedTextField1 = new javax.swing.JFormattedTextField();
        dateRender1 = new br.com.imprimindo.conteudo.itext.DateRender();

        FormListener formListener = new FormListener();

        org.jdesktop.swingbinding.JTableBinding jTableBinding = org.jdesktop.swingbinding.SwingBindings.createJTableBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.AutoBinding.UpdateStrategy.READ_WRITE, list, masterTable);
        org.jdesktop.swingbinding.JTableBinding.ColumnBinding columnBinding = jTableBinding.addColumnBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${id}"));
        columnBinding.setColumnName("Id");
        columnBinding.setColumnClass(Integer.class);
        columnBinding = jTableBinding.addColumnBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${codigo}"));
        columnBinding.setColumnName("Codigo");
        columnBinding.setColumnClass(String.class);
        columnBinding = jTableBinding.addColumnBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${ddv}"));
        columnBinding.setColumnName("Ddv");
        columnBinding.setColumnClass(java.time.LocalDate.class);
        columnBinding = jTableBinding.addColumnBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${descricao}"));
        columnBinding.setColumnName("Descricao");
        columnBinding.setColumnClass(String.class);
        columnBinding = jTableBinding.addColumnBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${estoque}"));
        columnBinding.setColumnName("Estoque");
        columnBinding.setColumnClass(Integer.class);
        columnBinding = jTableBinding.addColumnBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${valor}"));
        columnBinding.setColumnName("Valor");
        columnBinding.setColumnClass(Double.class);
        bindingGroup.addBinding(jTableBinding);
        jTableBinding.bind();
        masterScrollPane.setViewportView(masterTable);
        if (masterTable.getColumnModel().getColumnCount() > 0) {
            masterTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setCellRenderer(null);
        }

        idLabel.setText("Id:");

        codigoLabel.setText("Codigo:");

        ddvLabel.setText("Ddv:");

        descricaoLabel.setText("Descricao:");

        estoqueLabel.setText("Estoque:");

        valorLabel.setText("Valor:");

        org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Binding binding = org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Bindings.createAutoBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.AutoBinding.UpdateStrategy.READ_WRITE, masterTable, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${selectedElement.id}"), idField, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BeanProperty.create("text"));
        binding.setSourceUnreadableValue("null");
        bindingGroup.addBinding(binding);
        binding = org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Bindings.createAutoBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.AutoBinding.UpdateStrategy.READ, masterTable, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${selectedElement != null}"), idField, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BeanProperty.create("enabled"));
        bindingGroup.addBinding(binding);

        binding = org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Bindings.createAutoBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.AutoBinding.UpdateStrategy.READ_WRITE, masterTable, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${selectedElement.codigo}"), codigoField, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BeanProperty.create("text"));
        binding.setSourceUnreadableValue("null");
        bindingGroup.addBinding(binding);
        binding = org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Bindings.createAutoBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.AutoBinding.UpdateStrategy.READ, masterTable, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${selectedElement != null}"), codigoField, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BeanProperty.create("enabled"));
        bindingGroup.addBinding(binding);

        binding = org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Bindings.createAutoBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.AutoBinding.UpdateStrategy.READ_WRITE, masterTable, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${selectedElement.descricao}"), descricaoField, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BeanProperty.create("text"));
        binding.setSourceUnreadableValue("null");
        bindingGroup.addBinding(binding);
        binding = org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Bindings.createAutoBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.AutoBinding.UpdateStrategy.READ_WRITE, masterTable, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${selectedElement != null}"), descricaoField, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BeanProperty.create("enabled"));
        bindingGroup.addBinding(binding);

        binding = org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Bindings.createAutoBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.AutoBinding.UpdateStrategy.READ_WRITE, masterTable, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${selectedElement.estoque}"), estoqueField, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BeanProperty.create("text"));
        binding.setSourceUnreadableValue("null");
        bindingGroup.addBinding(binding);
        binding = org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Bindings.createAutoBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.AutoBinding.UpdateStrategy.READ, masterTable, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${selectedElement != null}"), estoqueField, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BeanProperty.create("enabled"));
        bindingGroup.addBinding(binding);

        binding = org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Bindings.createAutoBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.AutoBinding.UpdateStrategy.READ_WRITE, masterTable, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${selectedElement.valor}"), valorField, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BeanProperty.create("text"));
        binding.setSourceUnreadableValue("null");
        bindingGroup.addBinding(binding);
        binding = org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Bindings.createAutoBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.AutoBinding.UpdateStrategy.READ, masterTable, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${selectedElement != null}"), valorField, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BeanProperty.create("enabled"));
        bindingGroup.addBinding(binding);

        saveButton.setText("Save");
        saveButton.addActionListener(formListener);

        refreshButton.setText("Refresh");
        refreshButton.addActionListener(formListener);

        newButton.setText("New");
        newButton.addActionListener(formListener);

        deleteButton.setText("Delete");

        binding = org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Bindings.createAutoBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.AutoBinding.UpdateStrategy.READ, masterTable, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${selectedElement != null}"), deleteButton, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BeanProperty.create("enabled"));
        bindingGroup.addBinding(binding);

        deleteButton.addActionListener(formListener);

        jFormattedTextField1.setFormatterFactory(new javax.swing.text.DefaultFormatterFactory(new javax.swing.text.DateFormatter()));

        binding = org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Bindings.createAutoBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.AutoBinding.UpdateStrategy.READ_WRITE, masterTable, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${selectedElement.ddv}"), jFormattedTextField1, org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BeanProperty.create("value"));
        bindingGroup.addBinding(binding);

        dateRender1.setText("dateRender1");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addComponent(idLabel)
                                    .addComponent(codigoLabel)
                                    .addComponent(ddvLabel)
                                    .addComponent(descricaoLabel)
                                    .addComponent(estoqueLabel)
                                    .addComponent(valorLabel))
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addComponent(idField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 541, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                    .addComponent(codigoField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 541, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                    .addComponent(descricaoField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 541, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                    .addComponent(estoqueField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 541, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                    .addComponent(valorField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 541, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                    .addComponent(jFormattedTextField1)))
                            .addComponent(masterScrollPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 595, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(29, 29, 29)
                        .addComponent(dateRender1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(newButton)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(deleteButton)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(refreshButton)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(saveButton)))
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        layout.linkSize(javax.swing.SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL, new java.awt.Component[] {deleteButton, newButton, refreshButton, saveButton});

        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(masterScrollPane, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 130, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(idLabel)
                    .addComponent(idField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(codigoLabel)
                    .addComponent(codigoField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(ddvLabel)
                    .addComponent(jFormattedTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(descricaoLabel)
                    .addComponent(descricaoField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(estoqueLabel)
                    .addComponent(estoqueField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(valorLabel)
                    .addComponent(valorField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(saveButton)
                            .addComponent(refreshButton)
                            .addComponent(deleteButton)
                            .addComponent(newButton))
                        .addContainerGap())
                    .addComponent(dateRender1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
        );

        bindingGroup.bind();
    }

    // Code for dispatching events from components to event handlers.

    private class FormListener implements java.awt.event.ActionListener {
        FormListener() {}
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            if (evt.getSource() == saveButton) {
                Form.this.saveButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
            else if (evt.getSource() == refreshButton) {
                Form.this.refreshButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
            else if (evt.getSource() == newButton) {
                Form.this.newButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
            else if (evt.getSource() == deleteButton) {
                Form.this.deleteButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        }
    }// </editor-fold>                        


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void refreshButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
        entityManager.getTransaction().rollback();
        entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        java.util.Collection data = query.getResultList();
        for (Object entity : data) {
            entityManager.refresh(entity);
        }
        list.clear();
        list.addAll(data);
    }                                             

    private void deleteButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
        int[] selected = masterTable.getSelectedRows();
        List<br.com.imprimindo.conteudo.itext.Produto> toRemove = new ArrayList<br.com.imprimindo.conteudo.itext.Produto>(selected.length);
        for (int idx = 0; idx < selected.length; idx++) {
            br.com.imprimindo.conteudo.itext.Produto p = list.get(masterTable.convertRowIndexToModel(selected[idx]));
            toRemove.add(p);
            entityManager.remove(p);
        }
        list.removeAll(toRemove);
    }                                            

    private void newButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        br.com.imprimindo.conteudo.itext.Produto p = new br.com.imprimindo.conteudo.itext.Produto();
        entityManager.persist(p);
        list.add(p);
        int row = list.size() - 1;
        masterTable.setRowSelectionInterval(row, row);
        masterTable.scrollRectToVisible(masterTable.getCellRect(row, 0, true));
    }                                         

    private void saveButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        try {
            entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
            entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        } catch (RollbackException rex) {
            rex.printStackTrace();
            entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
            List<br.com.imprimindo.conteudo.itext.Produto> merged = new ArrayList<br.com.imprimindo.conteudo.itext.Produto>(list.size());
            for (br.com.imprimindo.conteudo.itext.Produto p : list) {
                merged.add(entityManager.merge(p));
            }
            list.clear();
            list.addAll(merged);
        }
    }                                          


    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JTextField codigoField;
    private javax.swing.JLabel codigoLabel;
    private br.com.imprimindo.conteudo.itext.DateRender dateRender1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel ddvLabel;
    private javax.swing.JButton deleteButton;
    private javax.swing.JTextField descricaoField;
    private javax.swing.JLabel descricaoLabel;
    private javax.persistence.EntityManager entityManager;
    private javax.swing.JTextField estoqueField;
    private javax.swing.JLabel estoqueLabel;
    private javax.swing.JTextField idField;
    private javax.swing.JLabel idLabel;
    private javax.swing.JFormattedTextField jFormattedTextField1;
    private java.util.List<br.com.imprimindo.conteudo.itext.Produto> list;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane masterScrollPane;
    private javax.swing.JTable masterTable;
    private javax.swing.JButton newButton;
    private javax.persistence.Query query;
    private javax.swing.JButton refreshButton;
    private javax.swing.JButton saveButton;
    private javax.swing.JTextField valorField;
    private javax.swing.JLabel valorLabel;
    private org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BindingGroup bindingGroup;
    // End of variables declaration                   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Form.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Form.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Form.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Form.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setContentPane(new Form());
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                 int windowWidth = 615;
                int windowHeight = 337;
                java.awt.Dimension screenSize = java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
                frame.setBounds((screenSize.width - windowWidth) / 2, (screenSize.height - windowHeight) / 2, windowWidth, windowHeight);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

This is Date Render:

```
package br.com.imprimindo.conteudo.itext;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;


public class DateRender extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
            boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

        super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        if (value instanceof LocalDate) {
            this.setText(sdf.format((LocalDate) value));
        }
        return  this;
    }

}
```

this is the project in the
[github](https://github.com/WellingtonLins/LocalDateJTextField.git)
In the branch master it work fine, but the problem, it's in the branch  called "localdate"!
When you click on the masterTable fot to lod the data for jTextfileds..

Comment: Please include your code.

Comment: @user2004685   Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error because of this line:

```
this.setText(sdf.format((LocalDate) value));
```

You can't use `SimpleDateFormat` directly with `LocalDate`. You'll first have to convert the `LocalDate` to `Date` and then use the `SimpleDateFormat` with the converted `Date` object.

Here is a code snippet from @Sotirios answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30651556/2004685):

```
LocalDate localDate = ... ;
Instant instant = localDate.atStartOfDay().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant();
Date res = Date.from(instant);
```

More information is available here:
http://blog.progs.be/542/date-to-java-time

Answer (score 0):

As user *user2004685* said, you cannot use `SimpleDateFormat` directly with `LocalDate`. The simplest solution is to convert `LocalDate` to `java.util.Date` through `java.sql.Date`:

```
java.util.Date date = java.sql.Date.valueOf(localDate);
this.setText(sdf.format(date));
```

Related links:

- [LocalDate to java.util.Date and vice versa simpliest conversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33066904/localdate-to-java-util-date-and-vice-versa-simpliest-conversion)
- [Javadoc of DateFormat#format(Date)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#format(java.util.Date))